# Using TimeseriesGenerator for large videos to extract frames

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, moviepy

I want to train a many-to-many LSTM model to predict dance moves. I am using a relatively large [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTeEc2bSAVs), and my PC cannot handle to extract all frames in the video. I created a custom class with moviepy to extract frames by using given frame number.

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from math import ceil
import numpy as np
import time

class Video:
    def __init__(self,path,**kwargs):
        self.path       = path
        self.video      = VideoFileClip(str(path),**kwargs)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        duration = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(self.video.duration))
        return f"<{duration} - {self.path.name}>"

    def __len__(self):
        return ceil(self.video.duration*self.video.fps)

    def __getitem__(self,frame_num):
        frame   = self.video.get_frame(frame_num/self.video.fps)
        return frame
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for frame_num in range(self.__len__()):
            yield self.__getitem__(frame_num)
```

This custom class managed to extract single frames with given frame numbers.

```
PATH  = Path("data/HenryStickmin.mp4")
HENRY = Video(PATH, audio=False)
<00:59:54 - HenryStickmin.mp4>

frame_nums = np.random.randint(0, len(HENRY), 4)
plt.figure(figsize=(21,13))
for fig_num, frame_num in zip(range(5), frame_nums):
    plt.subplot(221 + fig_num)
    plt.imshow(HENRY[frame_num])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title(f'Frame No: {frame_num}', fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image]

My next goal was to create timeseries dataset but I got this error

```
import tensorflow as tf
fps  = 30
gen  = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(HENRY, HENRY, fps * 2, sampling_rate=2, stride=fps)
X, y = gen[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-a7b22e584018> in <module>
----> 1 X, y = gen[0]

~\.conda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    370                                     self.stride, self.end_index + 1), self.stride)
    371 
--> 372         samples = np.array([self.data[row - self.length:row:self.sampling_rate]
    373                             for row in rows])
    374         targets = np.array([self.targets[row] for row in rows])

~\.conda\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    370                                     self.stride, self.end_index + 1), self.stride)
    371 
--> 372         samples = np.array([self.data[row - self.length:row:self.sampling_rate]
    373                             for row in rows])
    374         targets = np.array([self.targets[row] for row in rows])

<ipython-input-2-40570a429d12> in __getitem__(self, frame_num)
     13 
     14     def __getitem__(self,frame_num):
---> 15         frame   = self.video.get_frame(frame_num/self.video.fps)
     16         return frame
     17 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'slice' and 'float'
```

I wanted to train my model with 1 * FPS frame (1 seconds) to predict 1 * FPS frames (1 second), and expected to get something like this

```
X[0] = array(['frame[000]', 'frame[002]', 'frame[004]', 'frame[006]',
       'frame[008]', 'frame[010]', 'frame[012]', 'frame[014]',
       'frame[016]', 'frame[018]', 'frame[020]', 'frame[022]',
       'frame[024]', 'frame[026]', 'frame[028]', 'frame[030]',
       'frame[032]', 'frame[034]', 'frame[036]', 'frame[038]',
       'frame[040]', 'frame[042]', 'frame[044]', 'frame[046]',
       'frame[048]', 'frame[050]', 'frame[052]', 'frame[054]',
       'frame[056]', 'frame[058]'])

y[0] = array(['frame[060]', 'frame[062]', 'frame[064]', 'frame[066]',
       'frame[068]', 'frame[070]', 'frame[072]', 'frame[074]',
       'frame[076]', 'frame[078]', 'frame[080]', 'frame[082]',
       'frame[084]', 'frame[086]', 'frame[088]', 'frame[090]',
       'frame[092]', 'frame[094]', 'frame[096]', 'frame[098]',
       'frame[100]', 'frame[102]', 'frame[104]', 'frame[106]',
       'frame[108]', 'frame[110]', 'frame[112]', 'frame[114]',
       'frame[116]', 'frame[118]'])
```

How can I create a generator to extract (data, target) =(1  second, 1 second) frames from my video?

Comment: I don't exactly know how `__getitem__` works, but this looks like a simple misunderstanding of it. You need to convert `frame_num` from a `'slice'` to a `'int'` or `'float'`.

Answer (score 0):

The list comp run by keras, `samples = np.array([self.data[row - self.length:row:self.sampling_rate]` , is passing a `slice` object into your `__getitem__`. You'll have to handle both a `slice` object, and your `integer` (assuming you want to access your data this way).

I'm not sure if this will work the way you intend, but it should give you a good starting point.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from math import ceil
import time


class VideoFileClip():
    def __init__(self, path, **kwargs):
        self.path = Path(path)
        self.duration = 100
        self.fps = 10

    def get_frame(self, num):
        return self


class Video:
    def __init__(self, path, **kwargs):
        self.path = Path(path)
        self.video = VideoFileClip(str(path),**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        duration = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(self.video.duration))
        return f"<{duration} - {self.path.name}>"

    def __len__(self):
        return ceil(self.video.duration * self.video.fps)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start, stop, step = key.indices(len(self))
            # not sure if you can be quite this lazy, but you can 
            # make this a list comp if needed
            return (self[i] for i in range(start, stop, step))
        return self.video.get_frame(key / self.video.fps)

    def __iter__(self):
        for frame_num in range(len(self)):
            yield self[frame_num]
```

```py
vid = Video("path")
vid[0]
vid[0:100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to improve my code but this is the best version so far

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import tensorflow as tf

from cv2 import cvtColor, COLOR_RGB2GRAY
from skimage import img_as_float

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

import math, random, time

class FrameGen(Sequence):
    def __init__(self,VideoPath,Xystep,ystep,BatchSize,isGray=False,isNormed=False,**kwargs):
        self.VideoPath          = VideoPath
        self.Video              = VideoFileClip(str(self.VideoPath),**kwargs)
        self.Xystep, self.ystep = Xystep,ystep
        self.BatchSize          = BatchSize
        self.isGray             = isGray
        self.isNormed           = isNormed

    def __repr__(self):
        duration = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(self.Video.duration))
        return f"<{duration} - {self.VideoPath.name} @ {self.Video.fps:3.1f} FPS>"

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(self.Video.duration*self.Video.fps/self.BatchSize)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        idx0, idx1  = idx*self.BatchSize,(idx+1)*self.BatchSize
        X, y        = self.__getbatch__(idx0,idx1)
        return X, y

    def __getbatch__(self,idx0,idx1):
        X, y = [], []
        for idx in range(idx0,idx1):
            i, j, k = idx0, idx0+self.Xystep-self.ystep, idx0+self.Xystep
            X_, y_  = [], []
            for frame_num in range(i,j):
                frame = self.__getframe__(frame_num/self.Video.fps)
                X_.append(frame)
            for frame_num in range(j,k):
                frame = self.__getframe__(frame_num/self.Video.fps)
                y_.append(frame)
            X.append(X_)
            y.append(y_)
        X = np.stack(X)
        y = np.stack(y)
        return X, y

    def __getframe__(self,frame_num):
        frame = self.Video.get_frame(frame_num/self.Video.fps)
        if self.isGray    : frame = cvtColor(frame, COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        if self.isNormed  : frame = img_as_float(frame)
        if frame.ndim < 3 : frame = frame[...,np.newaxis]
        return frame
      
PATH            = Path("data/HenryStickmin.mp4")
imW, imH, imC   = 70, 120, 1
HENRY           = FrameGen(PATH, 18, 6, 8, isGray=True, isNormed=True, target_resolution=[imW,imH])

>>> HENRY
<00:59:54 - HenryStickmin.mp4 @ 30.0 FPS>
>>> len(HENRY)
13479
>>> X,y=HENRY[13478]
>>> X.shape
(8, 12, 70, 120, 1)
>>> y.shape
(8, 6, 70, 120, 1)
```

**X[0,0,...,0]**
[image]

**y[0,0,...,0]**
[image]

I'm still not sure if this works fine, I think I should add something like stride to avoid using each frame. I'm basically trying to get [this](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/timeseries/) same function but with multiple targets.